# How come dynamically assigning a name using javascript fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically assign a name attribute to a level 2 header using jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/8ZTEb/

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("h2").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).html().toLowerCase()); 
    });
});​
```

Here is my long, but simple HTML.

```
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu sollicitudin urna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In tincidunt magna vel quam auctor sit amet tincidunt lacus euismod. Praesent bibendum odio nec nisl tempus dictum. Cras aliquet condimentum est luctus accumsan. Aenean lectus lacus, malesuada eu dictum eu, euismod ac purus. Aliquam ultrices egestas elit, nec scelerisque lorem suscipit in. In auctor bibendum ullamcorper. Aenean lectus arcu, fermentum sed aliquet quis, tristique vestibulum est. In nisi ligula, consequat non semper vitae, pharetra vel risus. Nulla odio augue, tincidunt quis bibendum id, ullamcorper vel eros. Proin feugiat imperdiet tellus, ut porttitor massa eleifend in. Praesent sed nisl sed dui vestibulum auctor. Maecenas viverra feugiat erat adipiscing porttitor. Aenean mattis tincidunt placerat.
</p>
<p>
Fusce aliquam, dui a facilisis porttitor, nisi dolor semper dolor, ac vestibulum elit lorem id lorem. Nam ut odio eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consequat tempor volutpat. Vestibulum cursus purus et nulla dignissim suscipit. Cras convallis dolor nec dolor volutpat vel rutrum magna eleifend. Nullam eget lorem orci. Vestibulum vel aliquam ligula.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam in tellus odio, ut gravida ante. Vestibulum vitae diam elementum dui ultricies hendrerit quis vitae ante. Vestibulum vel metus metus. Nulla in nulla et risus dictum lobortis at ac ligula. Nunc in dolor id sapien facilisis porttitor id vitae magna. Integer pretium faucibus felis, vitae tristique est condimentum egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Duis auctor molestie sapien, sed vestibulum dolor ornare in. Praesent lacus purus, luctus non suscipit eget, aliquet in nunc. Etiam bibendum, erat ut blandit vehicula, augue diam vestibulum ipsum, ut imperdiet libero est sit amet tortor. Quisque gravida porttitor augue, eu hendrerit libero ullamcorper eget. Sed at tortor nisi, a luctus nunc. Curabitur in fringilla velit. Nulla elementum hendrerit ante ac faucibus. Mauris ultrices pretium erat sit amet scelerisque.
</p>
<p>
Integer dictum diam vel orci laoreet vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec eu commodo dui. Quisque a diam mauris. Curabitur ornare sollicitudin ligula, in fringilla ligula porttitor et. Proin bibendum tincidunt orci, eget iaculis sem venenatis et. Integer eu eros magna, sed placerat augue. Cras eget est purus. Duis convallis gravida tempus. Curabitur a dolor ut nisl sodales rutrum. Maecenas eget diam quis turpis scelerisque mattis eget ac sapien. Sed commodo mattis tellus, sit amet tempor ligula placerat at.
</p>
<p>
Sed ornare faucibus tincidunt. Sed suscipit metus a massa feugiat dignissim. Maecenas auctor vulputate placerat. Vivamus pulvinar pharetra tincidunt. Nunc tempus ornare interdum. Vestibulum vitae magna lorem, quis luctus augue. Phasellus quam leo, dignissim vitae semper a, iaculis et lacus. Sed elit nunc, interdum sit amet dictum vitae, fermentum eget lorem. Phasellus nisi dui, varius ut lacinia et, condimentum sed tortor. Fusce eu orci et justo rutrum varius sit amet quis enim. Suspendisse id urna eget odio pellentesque lacinia in ut neque. Vestibulum ante lectus, placerat ac mattis vitae, tincidunt quis tortor. Morbi vel sem ut quam dignissim faucibus ut eu lorem. Aliquam laoreet arcu nec urna eleifend consectetur. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>
<h2>Bar</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu sollicitudin urna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In tincidunt magna vel quam auctor sit amet tincidunt lacus euismod. Praesent bibendum odio nec nisl tempus dictum. Cras aliquet condimentum est luctus accumsan. Aenean lectus lacus, malesuada eu dictum eu, euismod ac purus. Aliquam ultrices egestas elit, nec scelerisque lorem suscipit in. In auctor bibendum ullamcorper. Aenean lectus arcu, fermentum sed aliquet quis, tristique vestibulum est. In nisi ligula, consequat non semper vitae, pharetra vel risus. Nulla odio augue, tincidunt quis bibendum id, ullamcorper vel eros. Proin feugiat imperdiet tellus, ut porttitor massa eleifend in. Praesent sed nisl sed dui vestibulum auctor. Maecenas viverra feugiat erat adipiscing porttitor. Aenean mattis tincidunt placerat.
</p>
<p>
Fusce aliquam, dui a facilisis porttitor, nisi dolor semper dolor, ac vestibulum elit lorem id lorem. Nam ut odio eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consequat tempor volutpat. Vestibulum cursus purus et nulla dignissim suscipit. Cras convallis dolor nec dolor volutpat vel rutrum magna eleifend. Nullam eget lorem orci. Vestibulum vel aliquam ligula.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam in tellus odio, ut gravida ante. Vestibulum vitae diam elementum dui ultricies hendrerit quis vitae ante. Vestibulum vel metus metus. Nulla in nulla et risus dictum lobortis at ac ligula. Nunc in dolor id sapien facilisis porttitor id vitae magna. Integer pretium faucibus felis, vitae tristique est condimentum egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Duis auctor molestie sapien, sed vestibulum dolor ornare in. Praesent lacus purus, luctus non suscipit eget, aliquet in nunc. Etiam bibendum, erat ut blandit vehicula, augue diam vestibulum ipsum, ut imperdiet libero est sit amet tortor. Quisque gravida porttitor augue, eu hendrerit libero ullamcorper eget. Sed at tortor nisi, a luctus nunc. Curabitur in fringilla velit. Nulla elementum hendrerit ante ac faucibus. Mauris ultrices pretium erat sit amet scelerisque.
</p>
<p>
Integer dictum diam vel orci laoreet vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec eu commodo dui. Quisque a diam mauris. Curabitur ornare sollicitudin ligula, in fringilla ligula porttitor et. Proin bibendum tincidunt orci, eget iaculis sem venenatis et. Integer eu eros magna, sed placerat augue. Cras eget est purus. Duis convallis gravida tempus. Curabitur a dolor ut nisl sodales rutrum. Maecenas eget diam quis turpis scelerisque mattis eget ac sapien. Sed commodo mattis tellus, sit amet tempor ligula placerat at.
</p>
<p>
Sed ornare faucibus tincidunt. Sed suscipit metus a massa feugiat dignissim. Maecenas auctor vulputate placerat. Vivamus pulvinar pharetra tincidunt. Nunc tempus ornare interdum. Vestibulum vitae magna lorem, quis luctus augue. Phasellus quam leo, dignissim vitae semper a, iaculis et lacus. Sed elit nunc, interdum sit amet dictum vitae, fermentum eget lorem. Phasellus nisi dui, varius ut lacinia et, condimentum sed tortor. Fusce eu orci et justo rutrum varius sit amet quis enim. Suspendisse id urna eget odio pellentesque lacinia in ut neque. Vestibulum ante lectus, placerat ac mattis vitae, tincidunt quis tortor. Morbi vel sem ut quam dignissim faucibus ut eu lorem. Aliquam laoreet arcu nec urna eleifend consectetur. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>​
```

Why does clicking on the inline anchor labeled "Bar" not go anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your link is looking for an element with the name "bar" not "foo".</strike>

`<a href="#bar">Bar</a>` would find your H2 if the H2 was `<h2 name="bar">Foo</h2>` and not `<h2 name="foo">Foo</h2>` as it is now. You're assigning the html of the H2 element (foo) as the H2's name attribute when you want it to be "bar" which is the html of the anchor.

You can either change your link to `<a href="#foo">Bar</a>` or change your jQuery.

Update: Your code should work for most elements, however for the greatest compatibility you might also want to make sure the element has the same ID and name value.

The HTML5 standard suggests using the ID attribute instead of the name attribute for specifying the name of an anchor. Using the ID attribute should work for HTML4 in all modern browsers.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#hyperlink

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I sneakily have a `<h2>Bar</h2>` somewhere in the middle of my code though. Thanks!

Comment: The main point is to give the H2 elements the same name and ID for the most compatibility.

Comment: With [`<h2>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/h2.html) elements (as in other headings), [the `name` attribute is not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/global-attributes.html). Unless you're worried about Netscape v4, I'd use `id` rather than name.

Comment: Note: to make sure your [`id`s are valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) you'll also want to strip spaces. Also better to use `text()` rather than `html()` in case the `h2` has inner markup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you instead want to scroll based on the element's position on the page. You should instead find the offset of a specific element (which you can do via jQuery), and then call `window.scrollTo(offset)` like so:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollableLink">Bar</a>

$('.scrollableLink').click(function()
{
    // Some syntax might not be correct on the selector, but you get the general idea
    var offset = $('[name=' + $(this).text() + '").prop('offsetTop');

    window.scrollTo(offset);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a name=''><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></a>` is the syntax your looking for.  I use the [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function of jQuery to add the correct anchor references.  [fiddle for your thoughts](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZTEb/4/)

## javascript

```
$(function() {
        $("h2").each(function(index,elem) {
            $(this).wrap("<a name='"+$(this).text().toLowerCase()+"'></a>"); 
        });
    });​
```